# CSS3 gradient background set on body doesn't stretch but instead repeats?

Tags: css, gradient

ok say the content inside the `<body>` totals 300px high.

If I set the background of my `<body>` using `-webkit-gradient` or `-moz-linear-gradient`

Then I maximize my window (or just make it taller than 300px) the gradient will be exactly 300px tall (the height of the content) and just repeat to fill the rest of the window.

I am assuming this is not a bug since it is the same in both webkit and gecko.

But is there a way to make the gradient stretch to fill the window instead of repeat?

Answer (score 848, accepted):

Apply the following CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

**Edit:** Added `margin: 0;` to body declaration per comments ([Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219443/)).

**Edit:** Added `background-attachment: fixed;` to body declaration per comments ([Johe Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268125/)).

Comment: I also found out that I needed to add `margin:0;` on `body` or else I got a gap at the bottom of my page.

Comment: Interesting. What browser? You may want to use a CSS reset.

Comment: In Chrome and Safari, body { height: 100% } results in the page (but not the gradient) extending down out of the viewport.

Comment: @thSoft - Add `margin: 0;` to the body declaration as @Martin stated. I was able to verify this fix for Chrome 8 on Win XP.

Comment: thank you for this! I was having to add an extra div as a background layer to get this working for me before I read this.

Comment: I had to add a background-attachment: fixed; to the body to get rid of the bottom gap (Webkit).

Comment: background-attachment:fixed is fine unless you're using the background gradient to divide elements using the background gradient. I, for one, want the background gradient to be a visual divider between the header and the rest of my page, and with the background-attachment:fixed I have the header divider at the top of the page, even when I scroll down

Comment: @JonMitten - That application is somewhat out of the scope of this question. It sounds like you should be applying your gradient to a fixed height container surrounding your header instead of the body. In which case, you would not need to worry about the `height: 100%` declarations on `html` and `body`. All you should need is `background-repeat: no-repeat;` on the container.

Comment: @BryanDowning - Yes, indeed. Making a wrapper div inside the body has alleviated that issue, and the gradient goes all the way to the nth pixel, regardless of page height. However, I needed to create a top-level div, because my original top-level div had auto margins left and right, and the gradient would stop at the margins, leaving blank space to the left and right.

Comment: Setting a background to the body and then the height of the html tag to 100% does weird things in Internet Explorer. [Here's an example (png).](http://i.imgur.com/Efruc.png)

Comment: Make sure that `background-repeat` and `background-attachment` come _after_ your `background` rules. Otherwise, the background might still repeat.

Comment: @kellen - Good point, I would add that you must ensure `background-repeat` and `background-attachment` are defined in a selector with high enough specificity to beat any other `background` declarations.

Comment: Be sure to place these rules **AFTER** your gradient rules so they take precedence!

Comment: I've no idea how this works but it works and I won't question that

Comment: I have a page that's taller than the viewport, so setting `height: 100%` means that it resets after you scroll down enough.  This solution doesn't fix that unfortunately.

Comment: Just make sure you don't add background like below after following the above code 
`html,
body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#7e57c2), to(#48c2c57b)) fixed !important
}`
This will apply background twice, first to the body and then to the html tag as well. I made this mistake, hence sharing here.

Answer (score 184):

Regarding a previous answer, setting `html` and `body` to `height: 100%` doesn't seem to work if the content needs to scroll. Adding `fixed` to the background seems to fix that - no need for `height: 100%;`

E.g.:

```css
body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#cbccc8)) fixed;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in every browser I tested (Chrome [Mac], Safari [Mac], Firefox [Mac/Win7], IE9 [Win7] and Opera [Mac]) without the scrollbar side effect of the "height: 100%" solution. Thanks!

Comment: A note for those people using Sass/Compass. You can't set "fixed" directly in the mixin so to add fixed you add the property `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: If you want to have either the background fill the window, or the content (whichever is greater) then use `min-height:100%` (in compatible browsers)

Comment: I was able to execute the following code using Compass: @include background(linear-gradient(top, red 0%, blue 100%) fixed);

Comment: How would I add a third color?

Answer (score 45):

I know I'm late to the party, but here's a more solid answer.

All you need to do is use `min-height: 100%;` rather than `height: 100%;` and your gradient background will extend the entire height of the **content** without repeating, even if the content is scrollable.

Like this:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(#b5e48c, #457b9d);
}
```

There's a second solution though.

As others have said, adding the value `fixed` to the `background` declaration, will make the gradient extend the full height of the **viewport**.

Like this:

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(#b5e48c, #457b9d) fixed;
}
```

Granted, you still need to declare `min-height: 100%;` in the `html`.

Here's a demo in CodePen where you can play with both solutions: https://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/abwGBmz?editors=1100

Comment: Unless you need to set html height to 100%, for example if you need sticky footer

Comment: Amazing! This was really helpful

Answer (score 15):

Here's what I did to solve this problem... it will show the gradient for the full length of the content, then simply fallback to the background color (normally the last color in the gradient).

```css
   html {
     background: #cbccc8;
   }
   body {
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background: #cbccc8;
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#cbccc8));
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #cbccc8);
     filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cbccc8');
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
```

I've tested this in FireFox 3.6, Safari 4, and Chrome, I keep the background-color in the body for any browsers that for some reason don't support styling the HTML tag.

Answer (score 14):

Setting `html { height: 100%}` can wreak havoc with IE. [Here's an example (png).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7fK4.png) But you know what works great? Just set your background on the `<html>` tag.

```css
html {
  -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000);
  /* etc. */
}
```

Background extends to the bottom and no weird scrolling behavior occurs. You can skip all of the other fixes. And this is broadly supported. I haven't found a browser that doesn't let you apply a background to the html tag. It's perfectly valid CSS and has been for a while. :)

Comment: @Lynda That's not very helpful feedback. Would you mind providing a case where it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I am unsure why it doesn't work. You can add a gradient to `html` but it stops part way down the page in my case. Adding `background-attachment:fixed` does solve the issue. I've seen this happen on more than one site but haven't been able to find the cause.

Comment: The point of this solution is that it worked across browsers (in 2012, by the way). But you still don't indicate what browser you're talking about. If you're still having trouble, try adding `html, body { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: True. It happens in Firefox and Chrome (didn't test in other browsers) and I tried height and various other settings without any luck (except background-attachment). Oh well, not a big deal and hopefully your answer still works for most. =>

Comment: Still have to fool with no-repeat and fixed.

Answer (score 12):

There is a lot of partial information on this page, but not a complete one. Here is what I do:

1. Create a gradient here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
2. Set gradient on HTML instead of BODY.
3. Fix the background on HTML with "background-attachment: fixed;"
4. Turn off the top and bottom margins on BODY
5. (optional) I usually create a `<DIV id='container'>` that I put all of my content in

Here is an example:

```
html {  
  background: #a9e4f7; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #a9e4f7 0%, #0fb4e7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#a9e4f7), color-stop(100%,#0fb4e7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */ 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #a9e4f7 0%,#0fb4e7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #a9e4f7 0%,#0fb4e7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #a9e4f7 0%,#0fb4e7 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #a9e4f7 0%,#0fb4e7 100%); /* W3C */ 
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a9e4f7', endColorstr='#0fb4e7',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* OPTIONAL: div to store content.  Many of these attributes should be changed to suit your needs */
#container
{
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px 20px #333;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

This has been tested with IE, Chrome, and Firefox on pages of various sizes and scrolling needs.

Comment: Great! I was using colorzilla and the main answer didn't work for me. This one did. Thank you! :)

Comment: Why is your preference to do it on HTML, not on BODY?

Comment: @sashaikevich Great question.  I haven't hardly looked at this answer in 5 years so I don't remember at all.  The reason I did it might not even still apply with all of the browser updates.  If you moved it all to body, I'd be curious if it worked the same.

Comment: @RickSmith Nope, I styled html. But, I did move the rules to apply to body just now to check, and that made no difference. Maybe it was an old browser thing...

Answer (score 7):

Adding a space and the word *fixed* to the end should be sufficient. No need to set heights.

```
body{
    background: linear-gradient(#e4efe9,#93a5cf) fixed;
}
```

Comment: The "space" between the last parenthesis and the notation `fixed`, is required in the `background` shorthand syntax. So the "space" isn't the solution, but the notation `fixed`. Which it's a different solution because unlike mine above, the gradient background extends the height of the **viewport**, whereas mine, extends the height of the **content**. I think this is a great solution as well.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, the space between the last parenthesis and the notation `fixed` is NOT required.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Dirty; maybe could you just add a min-height: 100%; to the html, and body tags? That or at least set a default background color that is the end gradient color as well.

Comment: The default background set as the end gradient color would be a great solution if the gradient stopped, but it doesn't just stop it repeats so the default background would only be seen if the gradient is unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble getting the answers in here to work.
I found it worked better to fix a full-size div in the body, give it a negative z-index, and attach the gradient to it.

```
<style>

  .fixed-background {
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1000;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .blue-gradient-bg {
    background: #134659; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #134659 , #2b7692); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #134659, #2b7692); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #134659, #2b7692); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #134659 , #2b7692); /* Standard syntax */
  }

  body{
    margin: 0;
  }

</style>

<body >
 <div class="fixed-background blue-gradient-bg"></div>
</body>
```

Here's a full sample
https://gist.github.com/morefromalan/8a4f6db5ce43b5240a6ddab611afdc55

Answer (score 0):

I have used this CSS code and it worked for me:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #f6cb4a; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f2b600 0%, #f6cb4a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f2b600), color-stop(100%,#f6cb4a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2b600 0%,#f6cb4a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f2b600 0%,#f6cb4a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f2b600 0%,#f6cb4a 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #f2b600 0%,#f6cb4a 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2b600', endColorstr='#f6cb4a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

A related information is that you can create your own great gradients at http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

/Sten

Answer (score -1):

```
background: #13486d; /* for non-css3 browsers */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9dc3c3),   to(#13486d));  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #9dc3c3,  #13486d);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9dc3c3', endColorstr='#13486d');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on the key aspects of your solution.

Answer (score -1):

this is what I did:

```
html, body {
height:100%;
background: #014298 ;
}
body {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#5c9cf2), color-stop(100%,#014298));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(92,156,242,1) 0%, rgba(1,66,152,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5c9cf2 0%,#014298 100%);

/*I added these codes*/
margin:0;
float:left;
position:relative;
width:100%;
}
```

before I floated the body, there was a gap on top, and it was showing the background color of html. if I remove the bgcolor of html, when I scroll down, the gradient is cut. so I floated the body and set it's position to relative and the width to 100%. it worked on safari, chrome, firefox, opera, internet expl.. oh wait. :P

what do you guys think?

Answer (score -4):

instead of 100% i just add some pixxel got this now and it works for whole page without gap:

```
html {     
height: 1420px; } 
body {     
height: 1400px;     
margin: 0;     
background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Comment: what about pages with > 1420 px in height?