# CSS background gradient covering whole page

Tags: css

I'm trying to make my background gradient cover the whole page (at least in Firefox for the moment):

```
body{
background: -moz-radial-gradient(60% 40%, closest-corner, purple, #2F2727);
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. My gradient repeats.

Comment: New Firefox doesn't require the moz prefix anymore

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 gradient background set on body doesn't stretch but instead repeats?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869212/css3-gradient-background-set-on-body-doesnt-stretch-but-instead-repeats)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add background-repeat: no-repeat;

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, logically, this should work:

```
$("body").css( 'background', '-moz-radial-gradient(' + window.innerWidth + 'px ' + window.innerHeight + 'px, closest-corner, purple, #2F2727)' );
```

Although, it produces a background completely `#2F2727` color, so it might not be your best bet, but that finds the height and width of the window and sets the gradient accordingly.

Comment: Like you said it does work but it doesn't produce the gradient. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't know, actually. It seems like it should work. There's probably something about gradients.