# CSS background 100% height

Tags: css, background, cover

```
html,body{
    background: linear-gradient(to right top, #336e7b 0%, #8e44ad 50%, #e74c3c 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #abb7b7;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/losiuhoi/1ujk40wh/1/

How can I set the background of body to 100% height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set height of the body to 100%, otherwise it takes only as much as it's necessary for content (`.msg` div).

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/1ujk40wh/2/

Comment: If I set the height of ".msg" class to 2000px, how can I extend the background(no-repeat)?

Comment: Maybe `fixed` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869212/css3-gradient-background-set-on-body-doesnt-stretch-but-instead-repeats

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can just place `height: 100%` inside the body...

http://jsfiddle.net/go5htxj7/