# Background gradient not taking entire page length, instead it is repeating

Tags: html, css, css-float, gradient

I am facing two issues.

First issue is that my background gradient is not taking up the entire length of the page. Instead it is repeating.

Second issue is that my aside element is not taking up the entire height of the page.

HTML and CSS can be viewed in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mcsjz4j1/

```
.aside {
width: 20%;
float: left;
color: black;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
height: 100%;
}

.list {
width: 80%;
float: right;
color: white;
height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your body's height isn't the full height of the page. This can be corrected with these css lines;

```
html{
  min-height: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

That should fix the background not covering all the way down.

For the aside, making it absolute positioned, with top and bottom at 0 will stretch it all the way.

```
.aside {
  width: 20%;
  /*margin-top: 4%;*/
  color: black;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mcsjz4j1/21/

Comment: This worked for me. The other solutions provided did not. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you believe the answer is correct, you should accept it

Answer (score 1):

Give min-height:100% for your aside css.

```
.aside {
  width: 20%;
  /*margin-top: 4%;*/
  float: left;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

For other issue, check this

[CSS3 gradient background set on body doesn't stretch but instead repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869212/css3-gradient-background-set-on-body-doesnt-stretch-but-instead-repeats)

Comment: Unfortunately the issue remained with the provided solution. However the solution provided by gedc worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
}

body {
background: rgba(117,137,12,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(117,137,12,1) 0%, rgba(164,179,87,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(117,137,12,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(164,179,87,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(117,137,12,1) 0%, rgba(164,179,87,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(117,137,12,1) 0%, rgba(164,179,87,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(117,137,12,1) 0%, rgba(164,179,87,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(117,137,12,1) 0%, rgba(164,179,87,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#75890c', endColorstr='#a4b357', GradientType=0 );
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```