# Why is this radial gradient coming out striped?

Tags: html, css, gradient

Why does the radial gradient code found here:
[generated gradient](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'-moz-radial-gradient%5C%28center%5C%2C%5C%20ellipse%5C%20cover%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28216%5C%2C215%5C%2C221%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%280%5C%2C9%5C%2C20%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B')

```
body {
    background: rgba(216,215,221,1);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(enter code here216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(216,215,221,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,9,20,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d8d7dd', endColorstr='#000914', GradientType=1 );
}
```

come out striped like seen here:
[codepen of generated gradient](https://codepen.io/Neil-G/pen/EXWEgV)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 gradient background set on body doesn't stretch but instead repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869212/css3-gradient-background-set-on-body-doesnt-stretch-but-instead-repeats)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, good catch, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You get weirdness since the body element isn't full-height by default. This fixes it:

```css
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
background: rgba(216,215,221,1);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(216,215,221,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,9,20,1)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d8d7dd', endColorstr='#000914', GradientType=1 );
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Please use voting and acceptance rather than "thank you" comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you put "body" in front, it's acting like each line of text is where the gradient will start. Change "body" in your css to ".this" and then put that in a div class, you'll see the gradient.

```css
.this {
    background: rgba(216,215,221,1);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(enter code here216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(216,215,221,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,9,20,1)));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(216,215,221,1) 0%, rgba(0,9,20,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d8d7dd', endColorstr='#000914', GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<div class="this">hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>hkhkj<br>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks for your help