# Duplicated body area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problem with duplicating body area, wchich looks like this:

[image: screen]

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean the fact that the gradient doesn't cover the whole body?
Also provide some code, please.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: try with `background-repeat: none;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869212/css3-gradient-background-set-on-body-doesnt-stretch-but-instead-repeats). Should set you on the right track.

Comment: tried that: now it's not fitting the screen - https://i.imgur.com/DKbwixf.png

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  **IMAGES of code are not acceptable.**

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background-size to fit the whole element by using `background-size:cover` .

```css
body {
width:100%;
height: 600px;
background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Do i must define constant height - 600px? what with the smaller devices?

Comment: No, I just added the height for demonstration purposes. You can keep your height as-is.

Answer (score 0):

this should fix it, the background will only show once

```
body {
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: tried that: now it's not fitting the screen - https://i.imgur.com/DKbwixf.png

Comment: the one from @Maharkus should work, you can change the height to 100% to set it to full screen