# linear-gradient() forming dashed lines

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm opening an HTML file with no content, just the full html skeleton. i styled the html by using this linear-gradient

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
```

instead of getting this expected outcome [image: expected]

I get this instead. 
[image]

This example comes from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: it works, but i dont understand why not one single tutorial has mentioned this or why it happens in the first place. Tomorrow I will have to learn this even more.

Comment: @Lazaro check the duplicate and you will get the detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

So what happens here is that the `<html>` element is just special. It is the height of the viewport, because it has to be, and it defaults to `overflow:auto;`. and yet, it's height is not explicitly defined, it is granted by the browser. So the gradient doesn't know where to get it's height value, and goes insane.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
```

If we give the `<html>` element an explicit height, then all is fine. In fact not giving the `<html>` element a height of 100% tends to be the cause of many issues, that are all fixed by giving `<html>` a height. `min-height: 100%;` will work as well.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
```

You could alternatively give the gradient itself a height of 100vh.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
  background-size: 100% 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in [CSS3 gradient background on body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869212/css3-gradient-background-set-on-body-doesnt-stretch-but-instead-repeats)

```
html{
 height:100%
}
body{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:linear-gradient(red, black);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:100%
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Linear gradient background</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```