# Linear Gradient in CSS

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have been learning CSS and I was trying the
`linear-gradient()`.

This works fine when I use "to right".

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,  #92EFFD, ##4E65FF);
```

My actual code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      body{
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #92EFFD, #4E65FF)
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

But when I remove "to right" it's like:

```
background-image: linear-gradient( #92EFFD, #4E65FF);
```

My actual code in this case:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      body{
        background-image: linear-gradient(#92EFFD, #4E65FF)
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The out put is this.
[image]

**What I wanted is to set the linear gradient top to bottom but it is not working**

Am I doing wrong anywhere or my code is wrong. Can you help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 gradient background set on body doesn't stretch but instead repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869212/css3-gradient-background-set-on-body-doesnt-stretch-but-instead-repeats)

Comment: min-height:100% on html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set gradient position you can simply use "deg" you can open inspect element in your browser to adjust according to your requirement.

Default position is top to bottom

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(#92EFFD, #4E65FF);
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg , #92EFFD, #4E65FF);
```

Comment: I tried this too but it was not working. Ok thanks I have already tried method from duplicate question.